# how to access file from app directory once the project is deployed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, vercel

i'm trying to deploy my project to vercel but i always get an error ENOENT when vercel try to access to my data files.

my project read json files (used as database files) located in my /app/jsons folder and also image files in my public folder.
i guess my error is to write the wrong path but i can't manage to find the solution.

here's the path for public folder(1) and json folder(2)on my first try:

```
fs.writeFile('./public/' + 'a file'), buffer)
await fs.readFile("./app/json/afile.json", 'utf8');
```

i then tried using process.cwd() :

```
fs.writeFile(process.cwd() + '/public/' + 'a file'), buffer)
await fs.readFile(process.cwd() + "/app/json/afile.json", 'utf8');
```

I'd like to keep my jsons private, it seems to me that they're not if they are in the public folder, but i may be wrong.
any ideas where's my mistake?

Comment: are you using ```yarn```? if yes then what version ?

Comment: try moving the folder to the root and then ```path.join(process.cwd(), 'folder name');```